# "ПОСТОЯ́ЛЕЦЬ" - калька з російської?

Tags: росіянізм, запозичені-слова, калька

Згідно [словника](https://slovnyk.me/dict/newsum/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%86%D1%8C), можна зустріти, що це слово використовується в українській мові

Але, як на мене, звучить воно російською.
То "ПОСТОЯ́ЛЕЦЬ" - калька чи ні?

Comment: Прибрано теги: [tag:етимологія], бо у запитанні не йдеться про походження; [tag:from-russian], бо цей тег використовується разом з [tag:переклад], а також [tag:граматика], бо не йдеться про правила граматики.

Comment: << звучить воно російською >> Можна розлогѣше?

Comment: В російській це слово частіше вживається. В українській - чула лише в кількох творах.  Тому маю сумнів, що воно українське, можливо, це всього лише авторське використання

Comment: << _В російській це слово частіше вживається_ >> Можете це якось підтвердити? « _В українській — чула лише в кількох творах_ >>, бо звідси можу зробити висновок, що ви просто російською більше читали.

Comment: Ні, читала більше українською. В описі свого запитання я додала "як на мене, звучить воно російською". Тобто це лише мої відчуття, припущення, а, отже, жодних підверджень. Саме тому задала запитання тут, щоб отримати відповідь від компетентних людей, а не подавала це як факт.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ні, це не калька і не русизм.

Слово «постоялець» в українській мові має синоніми «постоянець», «постояльник», «пожилець», але частіше — принаймні в українській літературі — вживається саме «постоялець».

Зокрема, словник Інституту мовознавства ім. Потебні НАН України під редакцією Жайворонка (2003 рік) ([ISBN 966-531-121-2](https://nashformat.ua/products/rosijsko-ukrainskyj-slovnyk-705025)) наводить «постоялець» і «пожилець» як переклади українською російського слова «постоялец», а чотиритомний словник Інституту української мови НАН України під редакцією Гриценка (2013 рік) (ISBN 978-966-1673-15-0) наводить преклади «постояльник», «пожилець» і «постоялець».

То ж, як бачимо, «постоялець» не є русизмом, це українське слово, принаймні на думку академіків і мовознавців.

Зауважу ще, якщо можна: той факт, що слово «постоялець» звучить майже як рос. «постоялец», не вказує на те, що це русизм. В українській мові існує чимало слів, які звучать навіть ідентично російським, але русизмами вони не є (напр. «правда», «вода», «собака» — це ж не русизми, чи не так?)

Comment: Ласкаво просимо до цього сайту і вітаю з першим якісним дописом! Я вписав ISBN словників і посилання на перший з них. Другий насправді називається В. Дубровський. «Словник московсько-український» і є перевиданням 1918/2013 рр.

Comment: Це нічого не доводить, вважаю інакше. Наприклад, є "брехати" — українське слово, а є "обманювати" — російський варіант (теж використовується і є у словниках).

Comment: дякую за відповідь!)